# Can I make a paper organizer with a small footprint?

Tags: organization, paper

I don't have much floor space for my stuff and have a really hard time getting organized. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: How many inches thick are the papers you want to organize?  Are they all standard letter size or a different size?  Is there a reason you're picturing the floor rather than on a desk / shelf / cabinet top?

Comment: You could consider making an organizer that hangs on the wall.  You can search for "hanging file organizers" on google images for inspiration.  You will see that there are even some made of fabric that should be simple to make.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to store your paper as paper? Or would it be acceptable to scan the paper and only keep the scanned file? That would save lots of space.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your papers are 8.5" by 11"...

These generic plastic letter trays can be stacked up to great heights. Doesn't take much floor or desk space and will nicely separate your different papers and notebooks.

[image: stackable letter trays]

You can add labels to each tray by wrapping a small piece of paper around the frame on one side and stapling the ends together. Or you can tape a label onto the tray above and have it hang over the front.

These trays can also be found in larger sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the following solutions for your problem:

- You can purchase [shelves](http://www.lokpal.com/images/storage-ware-housing-equipments/rotary-file-racks-midum.jpg) of this type because of space issues.
- arrange files using a color coding system.
- Label the files and keep it in the [drawer](http://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/s0273158_sc7?$splssku$) would be another good idea.
- You could also use alphabetical ordering to keep files in [drawer](http://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/s0273158_sc7?$splssku$).